# Create temp table with variable @user

Tags: sql-server

I have a Store procedure that receives a variable `@user` and creates a temporary table called with `@user` value for example #mrossi.

```
declare @user nvarchar(100)
    ,@sql nvarchar(100)
set @sql = 'CREATE TABLE #'+@user+'(Tipo nvarchar(10),Val float)'
exec(@sql)
```

The execution ends without issue, but the table is not created.

What do i wrong?

Comment: It is a scope issue.  The temp table evaporates when the session completes.   That said, being a temp table, there is really no reason to customize by user name.  Just use temp1, temp2, etc/

Comment: Ok, but in this SP I Insert values in this temp table and I use them to check some values, so why the system not created it but if I exec CREATE TABLE #mrossi(Tipo nvarchar(10),Val float) the system create it without issue?

Comment: As soon as you call this procedure, as written, it is created and then goes away. Anything you want to do with this temp table needs to happen inside of the procedure as @JohnCappelletti stated.

Comment: It does create the table, but it is dropped when the `EXEC` completes. This is generally a good thing, because it allows you to create temporary tables in dynamic batches without fear of clashing with something else. You can verify this with `EXEC('CREATE TABLE #Foo(ID INT IDENTITY); SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables'); SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables;`. Inside the batch, you should see `#Foo_______...`. Note that this is true even inside a stored procedure (this doesn't appear to be explicitly documented in either `CREATE TABLE` or `EXEC`, but it is how it works).

Answer (score 0):

once your stored procedure has been called, the temp table then 'drops out of scope' and is deleted when you drop back into any calling procedure.

You may have noticed that in SSMS the #temp table does hang around after you have called code in a window that makes a temp table.

You can experiment with ##temp tables which persist until the connection that created them gets closed.  But watch out, they are visible globally to all connections.

```
declare @user nvarchar(100), @sql nvarchar(100);

SET @user = 'don';

SET @user = @user + REPLACE(cast(newid() as nvarchar(100)),'-','');
print @user;
set @sql = 'CREATE TABLE ##'+@user+' (Tipo nvarchar(10),Val float)'
exec(@sql);
print @@error;
set @sql = 'INSERT ##' + @user + ' VALUES(''foo'',3.14)'
exec(@sql);

set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ##' + @user;
exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Ok, but in this SP I Insert values in this temp table and I use them to check some values, so why the system not created it but if I exec CREATE TABLE #mrossi(Tipo nvarchar(10),Val float) the system create it without issue?

Answer (score 0):

The table is created but you can not access the table or variable out side the script execution scope where the table is created. You can access the table as below-

```
declare @user nvarchar(100)
,@sql nvarchar(100)

SET @user = 'Test'
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE #'+@user+'(Tipo nvarchar(10),Val float)

SELECT * FROM #test'

EXEC(@sql)
```